# Make a guake style command-line in a Console Application

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, command-line-interface

I have an application that reads input with `Console.ReadLine();`

And the problem obviously comes when I have stuff coming out with `Console.WriteLine()` and

I want the user to actually see what he's typing.

I'm a linux user at my workplace and we use `Guake` alongside ordinary terminals.

I want to have my console application have the bottom row of the console the place where the input is taken from, and the output just pours in the console normally.

Is there a way to do that with `C# Console Application`?

Comment: There are enough cursor control commands for the console to write a small window manager; but all you really need is to erase the second to last line and position the cursor at the bottom again, right?

Comment: I don't know the exact details of implementation, I was hoping for stuff like library suggestions and stuff. Dealing with something that's already working is nicer then having to implement your own bug-probe code

Comment: Yes, there are some libs and you can google for them. Just don't ask here as asking for libraries or tools is off topic on SO today. But google will bring up old post with answers. I can't judge their quality or how suitable they are to you..